# The use of the construction "there is"/ there are without adverbials of place

Tags: grammar

Is it natural to omit adverbials of place with the construction *there is*/*there are*. For example:

> Person 1: How many people are there in the office?
>
> Person2: There are 20 people (in the office).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the fact that you're using "there is/are" doesn't really determine whether or not you can omit "in the office". You certainly can but that's mainly because "in the office" is already mentioned in the question. If the sentence isn't following a question, omitting "in the office" may cause a lack of information.

Bonus: Since "people" (the unit) is already mentioned in the question, you can also omit it.

> There are 20 (people).

Comment: You don't need to say *there are* either. You could simply answer *twenty* and the meaning would be clear. In fact, only giving the number is the most idiomatic response.

Comment: Most of the time people would say "20" or "20 people". Only if it's very formal do people actually say "There are 20 (people)".